# javafx how controlfx dialog box in FXML controller

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, javafx-2, controlsfx

how could i open a dialog box in fxml controller as it requires `stage`

```
 Dialogs.create()
    .owner(---what should i write here---)
    .title("Information Dialog")
    .masthead("Look, an Information Dialog")
    .message("I have a great message for you!")
    .showInformation();
```

I have added following jar

```
controlsfx-8.0.6_20.jar
controlsfx-samples-8.0.6_20.jar
fxsampler-1.0.6_20.jar
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **owner** is the *stage* that the Dialog windows will use.:

```
import org.controlsfx.dialog.Dialogs;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Diag extends Application{

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Dialogs.create()
        .owner(primaryStage)
        .title("Information Dialog")
        .masthead("Look, an Information Dialog")
        .message("I have a great message for you!")
        .showInformation();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

And as you may want to call it as a Dialog, you may as well call it as:

```
        Dialogs.create()
        .owner(new Stage())
        .title("Information Dialog")
        .masthead("Look, an Information Dialog")
        .message("I have a great message for you!")
        .showInformation();
```